# Find in Files (Regex) - Returning Consecutive Lines

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++, findinfiles

I need to return all occurrences of when three lines are consecutively written in a file.  I'm looking for the following:

```
FieldName=<some name>
Operator=<some operator>
Value=<some value>
```

Example File Content

```
MatchAny=FALSE
FieldValue=TRUE
Operator=Is less than
TotalFields=1
[OutputTarget0SelField0]
FieldName=ORIG-DATE
Operator=Is greater than
Value=20000101
[OutputTarget1]
```

To do this, I have been trying to use Notepad++ Find in Files functionality but I cannot seem to get the correct regular expression.

Here is what I've tried (in this case I'm assuming the two lines after FieldName= will always be Operator= and Value=)

[image]

Find what: `(FieldName=|Operator=|Value)` is also close, but obviously doesn't account for the fact that these lines need to be consecutive ("FieldName=" followed by "Operator=" followed by "Value=") and returns all single occurrences as well.

Comment: Could you give `^FieldName=[^\n\r]*[\n\r]+Operator=[^\n\r]*[\n\r]+Value=[^\n\r]*` a try?

Comment: @SebastianProske thank you for your response.  It does seem to work but the output just shows the start line of each occurrence... which may be a limitation of the Find in Files functionality.  So, for example, the three lines appear consecutively on line 633 but the output only shows the FieldName line:

Line 633: FieldName=ORIG-DATE

Line 1101: FieldName=DATE 

Line 1313: FieldName=DATE

Comment: If you double click on one of the matches, it should actually mark the full match in the file? Could you try this please?

Comment: Aw. I see. I didn't realize that's how it works.  Thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^FieldName=[^\n\r]*[\n\r]+Operator=[^\n\r]*[\n\r]+Value=[^\n\r]*` to match your 3 consectuve lines:

- `^FieldName=[^\n\r]*[\n\r]+` matches a start of a line, follwed by `FieldName=`, any amount of non-linebreaks and then one or more linbreaks. As you tagged your question with Windows, you might be able to replace `[\n\r]+` with `\r\n`, this also prevents empty lines from jumping into the match (which at the moment would be possible)
- `Operator=[^\n\r]*[\n\r]+` is basically the same for the Operator-Line
- `Value=[^\n\r]*` is again the same for the Value-Line, this time without the finishing linebreaks

As stated in the comments, this will only show you the first matched line in the find in files overview, but you can double click it, so it shows the whole match.